# Pandas merge on some columns; for some other columns take left if not NaN

Tags: pandas, merge

I have two dataframes `df1, df2` that I want to merge into one. I want to merge on some columns, `m_cols = ["m1", "m2"]`, while for another set of columns, `g_cols = ["g1", "g2"]`, I would like to use the values of `df1` unless they are `NaN` in which case I want the values from `df2`. (In my case, all NaNs arise because the merged row comes from `df2` only).

**Example**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "m1": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "m2": [21, 22, 23, 24],
    "g1": [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4],
    "g2": [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4],
    "b_df1" : ["a1", "b1", "c1", "d1"]
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "m1": [1, 2, 7, 8],
    "m2": [21, 22, 27, 28],
    "g1": [1.12, 1.22, 1.72, 1.82],
    "g2": [2.12, 2.22, 2.72, 2.82],
    "b_df2" : ["a2", "b2", "c2", "d2"]
})

g_cols = ["g1", "g2"]
merge_cols = ["m1", "m2"]

# Half-done merge to illustrate situation
df_half_merged = df1.merge(df2, how="outer", on=merge_cols, indicator=True, suffixes=('', '_df2'))
df_half_merged
```

Output:

```
| m1 | m2 | g1  | g2  | b_df1 | g1_df2 | g2_df2 | b_df2 | _merge     |
|----|----|-----|-----|-------|--------|--------|-------|------------|
| 1  | 21 | 1.1 | 2.1 | a1    | 1.12   | 2.12   | a2    | both       |
| 2  | 22 | 1.2 | 2.2 | b1    | 1.22   | 2.22   | b2    | both       |
| 3  | 23 | 1.3 | 2.3 | c1    | NaN    | NaN    | NaN   | left_only  |
| 4  | 24 | 1.4 | 2.4 | d1    | NaN    | NaN    | NaN   | left_only  |
| 7  | 27 | NaN | NaN | NaN   | 1.72   | 2.72   | c2    | right_only |
| 8  | 28 | NaN | NaN | NaN   | 1.82   | 2.82   | d2    | right_only |
```

I want the end product to be

```
| m1 | m2 | g1   | g2   | b_df1 | b_df2 |
|----|----|------|------|-------|-------|
| 1  | 21 | 1.1  | 2.1  | a1    | a2    |
| 2  | 22 | 1.2  | 2.2  | b1    | b2    |
| 3  | 23 | 1.3  | 2.3  | c1    | NaN   |
| 4  | 24 | 1.4  | 2.4  | d1    | NaN   |
| 7  | 27 | 1.72 | 2.72 | NaN   | c2    |
| 8  | 28 | 1.82 | 2.82 | NaN   | d2    |
```

That is, `g_cols = ["g1", "g2"]` should be taken from `df1` whenever not `NaN` and from `df2` otherwise. In this case, this only happens when the row is coming from `df2` only, as indicated in by `right_only` in the `_merge` column of the half-baked output `df_half_merged`.

**Additional info**

- Neither dataframe has a meaningful index
- I strongly prefer not to change order of columns
- The actual dataframes are of shape ~ 50,000 x 20
- The final application will combine several such dataframes for which I plan to use `reduce(func, [df1, df2, ...])` with function `func` solving the problem above.
- Better ideas about how to do this for a list of dataframes are of course welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After merge, select `NaNs`, mask and get values from relevant columns using `np.where`

```
df_half_merged=df_half_merged.assign(g1=np.where(df_half_merged.g1.isna(),df_half_merged.g1_df2, df_half_merged.g1),g2=np.where(df_half_merged.g2.isna(),df_half_merged.g2_df2, df_half_merged.g2)).drop(columns=['g1_df2','g2_df2','b_df2','_merge'])
print(df_half_merged)
 



    m1  m2   g1   g2  b_df1
0   1  21  1.10  2.10    a1
1   2  22  1.20  2.20    b1
2   3  23  1.30  2.30    c1
3   4  24  1.40  2.40    d1
4   7  27  1.72  2.72   NaN
5   8  28  1.82  2.82   NaN
```

Comment: @Stalpotaten sorry forgot to notify I had made edits. I gave you an upvote. To make people confidently use your question and my answer if they have similar, please upvote for my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Done! In case someone has the _exact_ question as I did, just skip dropping column b_df2.